# Mootools absolute TIP positioning

Tags: iframe, mootools, absolute, tooltip

I need to position a Mootool events calendar inside an Iframe.

Unfortunately the tool tip which appears on a date with events, get always cut by the boundary of the Iframe.

How can I set the tooltip position so that it's always at x=0 and y=0 of the container div (here "calcontainer")?

Here the piece of code which generates the tip

```
if (this.showtip) {
newTip = new   Tips(eventDiv, {
fixed: true
});
eventDiv.store('tip:title', time).store('tip:text', this.options.cEvents[i].title + '<br /><i>' + this.options.cEvents[i].location +'</i>')
;
}
```

here the html

```
<div  class="calcontainer" >
<div id="calBody"></div>
</div>
```

calBody is the div containing the calendar

Thanks

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ke5Wx/    Note: there is an external resource to MooECal.js

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with your fiddle, but here is an example where the calendar is possitioned at (0,0). http://jsfiddle.net/ke5Wx/2/ is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In reality I need the tooltip to be at 0,0 position of the calendar, not the calendar itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want the tooltips to be positioned 0,0 to the container ? then people will not understand that this tooltip is relevant for that date.

You set `fixed:true` - fixed is a flag that sais if the tooltip follow the mouse or stay fixed.

what you can do is either enlarge the iframe so it will contains also the gap of the tooltips 
or use the tips attribute `offset` or `windowPadding` which you can read about in the [Tips Docs](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/Tips)

Comment: Yes, I understand it can become an issue but the problem is that I have available only an iframe of the same size of the calendar, so showing the tooltip in "proper" position will result in a cut tooltip. I tried the offset and windowPadding but I fear I'm not able to use them in the first code piece mentioned in my initial post. Suggestions?

Comment: why can't you use them ? you can edit the script `http://www.surfdose.com/js/eventscalendar/mooECal.js` by yourself - what is the problem ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. Now it works. Please see my first jsfiddle. I added: offset:{x: -eventDiv.left-eventDiv.width, y: -eventDiv.top-eventDiv.height}